# Find the velocity of the mouse in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, mouseevent

How can i find the instantaneous vertical speed of the mouse at the ***exact*** moment that the mouse is released? i have the users dragging over a custom control and when they release i need to know this information so i can continue the object they were dragging using the vertical component of the velocity...

so for instance, if they were dragging at an angle, use trig to determine the vertical speed and then use that..

i cant just do distance over time, because the mouse can be moved at irregular speeds and this will not represent the correct velocity at all.

I was thinking that there might be a specific interval between the triggers of MouseMove that i could use, but im not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can i find the instantaneous vertical speed of the mouse at the exact moment that the mouse is released?

You can't. As Zeno made clear centuries ago, speed is only meaningful over a period of time. If I had to do it, I'd probably use a weighted moving average, so (for example) I computed the distance/time for each of the last 5 mouse movement messages, but their importance "decayed" over time. For example, I might multiply the most recent by 1, the next one back by .8, the next one back by .6, and so on. This way if (for example) they happen to slow down (or speed up) the movement just as they release the button, you still get a reasonable approximation of what they *were* doing just prior to that.

Comment: I guess Zeno made the comment before we inveted math then. Btw, in this case you have a discrete time-step.

Comment: @stefan: What exactly do you even think you're talking about?

Comment: @Jerry Coffin Just because you need time frames doesn't mean you can't say the velocity at the exact moment the button is released. It will never happen at time=0 nor at time<0. It cannot! So you are left with prety much any other time, and math will do the trick for you. ps a modern "mouse" isnt a two dimensional pixel-coordinates feeding apparatus..

Comment: @stefan: sorry, but no. Speed is given in units of distance per units of time. When you reduce the time to zero, the distance is also always zero. That means you have 0 divided by zero, which is undefined. The closest math gets to this is calculus, which will let you compute speeds as you *approach* infinitely close to instantaneous, but never let's you actually get *to* instantaneous. Calculus won't let you go where there's a discontinuity, which is exactly what happens in this case.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin You cant release the mouse button at time zero, its impossible. It would never have been pressed!

Comment: @stefan: the time when you release it doesn't matter. The point is that you can only compute the speed over a period of time prior, NOT simply at the instant it was released.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin How can you not have a period of time if you cant press and release the button at the same time? You over analyzed the original question, he says nothing about any time. Simply answering sampling/or similair without an off topic quote wouldve been OK.

Comment: @stefan: it doesn't matter how long you hold the button down. When you release the button it defines one point in time, not a period of time. The OP was very specific in asking about the speed at one specific point in time, not over a period -- and I simply included one sentence pointing out that it's not possible. At the risk of sounding arrogant: if you dislike such precision, you're in the wrong profession; you're clearly unsuited to programming.

Answer (score 5):

Consider pinvoking GetMouseMovePointsEx().  It can give you move history for up to 64 points.  Each point has a time stamp, allowing you to accurately calculate speed.  It gets you much more accuracy since the time stamp is not affected by any delays you may get from having the mouse move messages buffered in the message queue.  And you can get points in native mouse units instead of pixels.  Visit pinvoke.net for the declarations.

Comment: I tried to do this, but ran into some problems. See my question [GetMouseMovePointsEx: Bounds / MOUSEMOVEPOINT in (mp_in) problems](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25170813/2596334).

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is sample the mouse movement constantly and keep track of -say- the last 10 positions. Then when the mouse button is released you would have an array of measurements that would allow you to estimate the mouse velocity when the mouse is released.

I wrote a quick winform app to play with this idea. This computes the 
velocity for every mouse move. You need to play with the queue length.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;

namespace MouseVelocity
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        Queue timePoints;

        public Form1()
        {
            sw.Start();
            timePoints = new Queue(100);
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            addPoint(e);
        }

        private void addPoint(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            timePoints.Enqueue(new TimePoint(new Point(e.X, e.Y), sw.ElapsedMilliseconds));
            if (timePoints.Count == 40) timePoints.Dequeue();
            object[] array = timePoints.ToArray();
            TimePoint tip = (TimePoint)array[array.Length - 1];
            TimePoint end = (TimePoint)array[0];
            long deltaX = tip.point.X - end.point.X;
            long deltaY = tip.point.Y - end.point.Y;

            long distance = deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY;

            long deltaT = tip.time - end.time;
            double velocity_modulo = Math.Sqrt(distance) / deltaT;
            double velocity_X = deltaX / (double)deltaT;
            double velocity_Y = deltaY / (double)deltaT;
            label1.Text = string.Format("|V| = {0}; Vx = {1}; Vy = {2}", velocity_modulo, velocity_X, velocity_Y);
        }

    }
    public class TimePoint
    {
        public Point point;
        public long time;

        public TimePoint(Point pt, long ms)
        {
            point = pt;
            time = ms;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are asking to calculate speed at the end of the curve in the distance-time curve which is not possible in calculus

i suggest u better take some short time frame at the end of curve that suites u the best and calculate the speed it would be nearly the same