# Windows Time Stamp format (type of MOUSEMOVEPOINT return value)

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timestamp

I am using the native method `GetMouseMovePointsEx` ([pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetMouseMovePointsEx.html), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646259%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).
Refer to my related question: [GetMouseMovePointsEx: Bounds / MOUSEMOVEPOINT in (mp_in) problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25170813/2596334).

Because this function only returns new data when the cursor is moved, I need a way to check how old the data is (compare the point time stamps to an equivalent for **now**).
I think these values are the same format as [InputEventArgs.Timestamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputeventargs.timestamp%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but I'm not sure.

- How can I create a new Time Stamp in the same format for comparison?

Up until *now* I've only used `DateTime.Now` to get some value for **now**.
But this Time Stamp doesn't look anything like `DateTime.Now.Ticks`; so what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Environment.TickCount` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: So it is! How is this not documented anywhere!?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @WhyCry Thanks for the link. What I meant was, it should be in the documentation for [MOUSEMOVEPOINT structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645603%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation, but it's not.

Comment: It really isn't being affected by the Mouse's movepoints though. The Environment is handling it. I understand what you mean though. Perhaps they could/should post a link or a "related to" section with reference to Environment.